# Deadlock when calling async methods on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous

My problem is the following:

On the UI thread I have a button event, from where I call a service method:

```
private async void RefreshObjectsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objectService = new ObjectService();
    var objects = await objectService.GetObjects(UserInfo.Token);
}
```

The service method is:

```
public class ObjectService : ServiceClientBase, IObjectService
{
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<ObjectViewModel>> GetObjects(string token)
    {
        var response = await GetAsync<ObservableCollection<HookViewModel>>("uri_address", token);
        return response;
    }
}
```

And the GetAsync method which is implemented in ServiceClientBase:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string token)
{
    using (var client = CreateClient())
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            T retVal = default(T);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                retVal = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO log exception
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

When execution reaches **`GetAsync<T>()`**, the request is sent, I get a result and **retVal** contains a list of values. However after **`GetAsync<T>()`** execution ends, **`GetObjects()`** will not continue its execution anymore. I believe it's a deadlock as explained [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). However using the advices seen in the previous link didn't resolve my issue. It's clearly I'm missing something here. 
Can someone explain why is this deadlock happening, and maybe provide some further advice in resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example that others can run?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the reply. I created the example but it didn't reproduced. I executed again my app and surprise, now it's working correctly. I haven't modified the code at all. The only thing I did, was to install Microsoft Asp.NET Web API 2.2 Client Library NuGet package, for the example app. Maybe it installed or updated some dll in the GAC? (I don't know if you can install a binary into GAC from NuGet). However thanks, I hope it won't reproduce again...